# BJT common collector Hartley Oscillator

Tags: voltage, analog, oscillator

This question is specifically about the BJT Common Collector Hartley Oscillator. In the corresponding Colpitts oscillator the feedback fraction is equal to C1+C2/C1 where C1 is the capacitor with ends connected to the base of the BJT transistor(ignoring the DC blocking capacitor) and  the voltage output of the emitter follower and C2 is connected to the voltage output of the emitter follower  and GND.

Is the equation for the Hartley oscillator correspondingly the same(L1+L2/L1) where L1 is the inductor with ends connected to the base of the BJT transistor(ignoring the DC blocking capacitor) and and  the voltage output of the emitter follower and L2 is connected to the voltage output of the emitter follower and GND.

I need this for an exam I am writing tommorow.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hartley and Colpits are essentially dual, so yes, you'd calacuate the feedback fraction in the same way, for two inductors. A single tapped inductor gives you a further degree of freedom if you use one.